# FLutter LazyLoading not working if Listview builder is inherited inside ListView

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am lazyloading data from firestore using streambuilder and listview.builder. Listview. builder is nested insider listview.

When I am using only listview.builder lazy loading works, but it doesn't when nested in listview. Please help what I am doing wrong. I am new to flutter world.

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest `ListView`s. Use `CustomScrollView` and slivers instead. You can learn more from [the official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers) or other places such as YouTube tutorials or medium blogs.